# how to replace my existing WIFI system while keeping it working for a short transition period

Tags: migration

I have an old Orbi Netgear wifi working off a Verizon Modem.  I want to upgrade to a new Netgear Orbi Router 6.  Can I keep the old system up while I move across?
But I want to reuse the old SSID# and Password for easy transition?

Comment: How is the Orbi connected to the Verizon, WiFi? Is the Orbi the DHCP server in your local network (gives out IP addresses)?

Comment: If you want the same Wireless passwords and security, set up the basics in the new router including WAN and DHCP if it has this. Once ready, you should be able to cut over in 30 minutes or so.

Comment: You can connected to the new hardware, without giving it internet access, or simply connecting it to your current network.  All you would do is make your required changes.  You can have multiple access points with the same SSID if you want, you will still have to reauthenticate devices, so your not saving time by doing that.  *It takes less then 2 minutes to change the password and name of an access point.*

Comment: Thanks for respnses.Orbi Router is hard wired to the Verizon Modem